# What image size should I use to design book cover?

Tags: book, dimensions

I have got a project of Book Cover design. The client is telling me that book cover should be print ready and ready to upload on [Create Space](https://www.createspace.com/).

I know if design is in CMYK color mode, means it is print ready so no problem with this. [Create Space](https://www.createspace.com/) allows only 300dpi resolution cover design so my question is;

What image size should I use to design book cover?
*I am designing both front and back sides with spine.*

Comment: Voting to close because nobody can answer this question for you. You need to know what dimensions they want their book printed. Then if its getting properly printed and you're doing the front, back, and spine you need to know how many pages and the thickness of the pages to determine the width of the spine. A 400pg novel is going to have a much wider spine then a 60pg children's book. etc..

Comment: If you can't determine its complete image size then at-least tell me its front cover image size.

Comment: It should probably be the same size as the book?

Comment: **All** the information you need is at CreateSpace. There are specifications clearly detailed in their documentation.

Comment: Then this question should be closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy Way: Use the Template Generator:**

https://www.createspace.com/Help/Book/Artwork.do

---

**Hard Way: Follow the Specs:**

Create Space offers several book sizes as shown in this table:

[image]

The author will have to pick one of those sizes, interior page colors, and a page count. Once you know those, you should be able to determine the exact submission requirments following the Create Space guidelines.

You can find details about what you must submit here:

https://www.createspace.com/Special/Enterprise/Publisher/submission_guidelines.jsp

The spine calculation is described in more detail here:

https://www.createspace.com/Products/Book/CoverPDF.jsp

You can also find more details starting on page 40 of this guide:

[CreateSpace PDF Submission Specification](https://www.createspace.com/ServicesWorkflow/ResourceDownload.do?id=1583)